# How to write Eloquent relation for one table to another table two columns?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to join two columns with a table.

Here is my table structure for tasks table

```
| id           | assigned_by    | assigned_to   |
| :---         |     :---:      |          ---: |
| 1            | 1              | 2             |
| 2            | 1              | 3             |
```

Here is the table structure of users table.

```
| id           | name           | email         |
| :---         |     :---:      |          ---: |
| 1            |varun           | me@gmail.com  |
| 2            |mark            | mark@gmail.com|
```

I tried below code in `Task Class` it didn't work

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column on the User model. By convention, Eloquent will take the **"snake case"** name of the owning model and **suffix it with _id**. So, for your example, Eloquent will assume the foreign key on the User model is `user_id`.

However, your foreign_key is `assigned_by` and `assigned_to`, so you need to specify the foreign_key:

```php
public function assignedUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'assigned_to');
}

public function assignedByUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'assigned_by');
}
```

Comment: What relationship i want to write in ```User class``` ?

Comment: @Senthur User has many tasks, you can defined two diff types tasks: `public function beAssignedTasks() { return $this->hasMany(Task::class, 'assigned_to', 'id');} ....`